# fd close called from the different process than one on which open is called

Tags: linux, multithreading, file, process, file-descriptor

fd close is called from the differect process thatn one on which open is called.
Here TestProcess is opening a fd and when it is exiting we are receiving a close from same pid.
But sometimes in issue case we are not receiving close from same pid. Here pid printed is current->tgid

```
process_name: TestProcess started with pid = 750
process_name: TestProcess exit with pid = 750
process_name: TestProcess started with pid = 6809
process_name: TestProcess exit with pid = 6809
process_name: TestProcess started with pid = 7094
process_name: // For TestProcess PID 7094 we din’t received the close call
process_name: kworker/3:0 exit with pid = 38
```

Can anyone help how we can know that process which has called open exited in issue case?

Comment: Its difficult to answer without seeing the code. You need to analyze the debug logs(`/var/log/messages` or `dmesg` or appropriate path) to know sequence of events happens for `7094` process id.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).